# POP3 access settings

Tags: email, gmail, imap, pop3

I'm trying to use GMail to access another email acocunt using POP3. I have put in my username and password and am trying to connect to the server on port 143. I get the following error:

Server returned error: "Missing +OK response upon connecting to the server: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS LOGINDISABLED] Dovecot ready."

Can anyone tell me what this means? Am I connecting to the wrong server? The email administrator is being very unresponsive to my queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you are seeing is an IMAP server error not POP3, so either connect to POP3's port (110) or connect using an IMAP client to port 143.

Comment: +1 : It also happens if you select by mistake port 993 (IMAP) instead of 995 (POP3) in SSL connections.

Answer (score 4):

Gmail does not support IMAP (yet?)
You need to have a POP3 server.

"Missing +OK response upon connecting to the server" is typical answer from a POP3 client trying to get mails from an IMAP server

Comment: Thank you, you saved me :D whitelisting port 995 instead of 993 on firewall solved the problem!